# What verb should be placed in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

"In February 1917 it (set up) _____ the Women's Land Army to recruit women as farm workers."

What verb should be placed in this sentence? Is the construction of this question grammatically incorrect, or correct? I'm rather left baffled.

Answer (score 2):

It's testing whether you know that the simple past of *set up* is *set up*.

> In February 1917 it **set up** the Women's Land Army to recruit women as farm workers.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that the right sentence is "In February 1917 it was set up the Women's ..." if you didn't have mentioned the name replaced by the pronoun "it".

Comment: @RubioRic If you disagree with an answer, please write your own. Comments bypass the voting system.

Comment: I know the system and the possibility of writting my own answer but I can't explain why "was set up" is better or not than just "set up".

Comment: @RubioRic Passive voice (“to be verbed”) doesn’t work here because you’d need to move the object into subject position.